# Intercept @RequestHeader exception for missing header

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I have a method in controller with has parameter for example

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{blabla}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public void post(@RequestHeader("ETag") int etag)
```

If there is no ETag header in request - client gets 400 (BAD_REQUEST), which is not any informative.
I need to somehow handle this exception and send my own exception to client (I use JSON for this purpose).
I know that I can intercept exception via  @ExceptionHandler, but in that case all HTTP 400 requests will be handled, but I want that have missing ETag in headers.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should user an @ExceptionHandler method that looks if ETag header is present and takes appropriate action :

```
@ExceptionHandler(UnsatisfiedServletRequestParameterException.class)
public onErr400(@RequestHeader(value="ETag", required=false) String ETag,
        UnsatisfiedServletRequestParameterException ex) {
    if(ETag == null) {
        // Ok the problem was ETag Header : give your informational message
    } else {
        // It is another error 400  : simply say request is incorrect or use ex
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeap, I choose this solution with little modifications, but before you write it down :)

Answer (score 16):

You can also achieve this by use of annotation `@ControllerAdvice` from spring.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler{

    /**
     * Handle ServletRequestBindingException. Triggered when a 'required' request
     * header parameter is missing.
     *
     * @param ex      ServletRequestBindingException
     * @param headers HttpHeaders
     * @param status  HttpStatus
     * @param request WebRequest
     * @return the ResponseEntity object
     */
    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleServletRequestBindingException(ServletRequestBindingException ex,
            HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(ex.getMessage(), headers, status);
    }

}
```

The response when you access your API without the required request header is:

> *Missing request header 'Authorization' for method parameter of type String*

Like this exception, you can customise all other exceptions.

Answer (score 11):

In case Spring version is 5+ then the exact exception you need to handle is the `MissingRequestHeaderException`. If your global exception handler class extends `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` then adding an `@ExceptionHandler` for `ServletRequestBindingException` won't work because `MissingRequestHeaderException` extends `ServletRequestBindingException` and the latter is handled inside the `handleException` method of the `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`. If you try you're going to get `Ambiguous @ExceptionHandler method mapped for ...` exception.

Comment: You saved my life here...Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 8):

There are two ways to achieve what you are trying

First using `@RequestHeader` with `required` `false`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{blabla}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public void post(@RequestHeader(value="ETag", required=false) String ETag) {
    if(ETag == null) {
        // Your JSON Error Handling
    } else {
        // Your Processing
    }
}
```

Second using `HttpServletRequest` instead of `@RequestHeader`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{blabla}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public void post(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String ETag = request.getHeader("ETag");
    if(ETag == null) {
        // Your JSON Error Handling
    } else {
        // Your Processing
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) I need this header, so I can't do it non-required.
2) This is exactly what I want, but in more general way, for number of methods. I think there is more clean way to make this work then copy/paste "if(ETag == null)".

Comment: hi @shazin . is it possible to capture this @ request header in a base class somewhere and accessed everywhere else in individual methods? Writing this piece of code everywhere seems to be inefficient

Comment: @RuslanIslamov setting the required to false is not saying you don't need it, it is simply making it so that the method won't throw an exception if it is not there. You can still do a check on the value and check if it is null and then proceed how you normally would if the call omitted it.

Answer (score 4):

In Spring 5+ it is as simple as this. `ErrorResponse` is your own object to return

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ControllerExceptionHandler {

@ExceptionHandler(MissingRequestHeaderException.class)
public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleException(MissingRequestHeaderException ex) {
    log.error("Error due to: " + ex.getMessage());

    ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse();

    return new ResponseEntity<>(errorResponse, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

}

Comment: I had to tweak your code a bit, but your approach is exactly what I as looking for. 

`@ExceptionHandler(MissingRequestHeaderException.class)`
`public ResponseEntity<String> handleException(MissingRequestHeaderException exc) {`
`return new ResponseEntity<>(exc.getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);`
`}`

Answer (score 3):

Write a method with the annotation @ExceptionHandler and use ServletRequestBindingException.class as this exception is thrown in case of missing header

For example :

```
@ExceptionHandler(ServletRequestBindingException.class)
public ResponseEntity<ResponseObject> handleHeaderError(){

    ResponseObject responseObject=new ResponseObject();
    responseObject.setStatus(Constants.ResponseStatus.FAILURE.getStatus());
    responseObject.setMessage(header_missing_message);

    ResponseEntity<ResponseObject> responseEntity=new ResponseEntity<ResponseObject>(responseObject, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    return responseEntity;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to handle this in your request mapping, then you could create a Servlet Filter and look for the ETag header in the Filter.  If it's not there, then throw the exception.  This would apply to only requests that match your filter's URL mapping.

```
public final class MyEtagFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String etag = request.getHeader("ETag");

        if(etag == null)
            throw new MissingEtagHeaderException("...");

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

You'll have to implement your own MissingEtagHeaderException, or use some other existing exception.

Answer (score 0):

This is relatively simple. Declare two handler methods, one that declares the appropriate header in the `@RequestMapping` `headers` attribute and one that doesn't. Spring will take care to invoke the appropriate one based on the content of the request.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{blabla}", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "ETag")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public void postWith(@RequestHeader("ETag") int etag) {
    // has it
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/{blabla}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public void postWithout() {
    // no dice
    // custom failure response
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also intercept the exception without extending `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ControllerExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(ServletRequestBindingException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleServletRequestBindingException(ServletRequestBindingException ex) {
        // return a ResponseEntity<Object> object here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `@Nullable` to this request param, and in case of absence, request still enters the controller without throwing `MissingRequestHeaderException`, and you add manual validation to throw whatever you like in controller and handle in the ExceptionHandler.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom exception class e.g. `InvalidRequestHeaderException.java`. You can customise your exception message here.

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public class InvalidRequestHeaderException extends RuntimeException {

  public InvalidRequestHeaderException() {
    super("Invalid request header provided.");
  }
}
```

In your controller, you can throw an exception if the header provided is invalid.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{blabla}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public void post(@RequestHeader("ETag") int etag) {
  // some code
  
  if (!isSupportedPlatform(platform)) {
    throw new InvalidRequestHeaderException();
  }
  
  // some code
}
```

You can then create a ValidationHandler.java to handle these exceptions.

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ValidationHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

  @ExceptionHandler(value = {
      MissingRequestHeaderException.class,
      InvalidRequestHeaderException.class
  })
  protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleRequestHeaderException(Exception ex) {
    log.error(ex.getMessage());
    return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(ErrorResponse.builder()
        .status(String.valueOf(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value()))
        .reason(ex.getMessage()).build());
  }


  @AllArgsConstructor
  @Getter
  @Builder
  public static class ErrorResponse {

    private String status;
    private String reason;
  }
}
```

By using `MissingRequestHeaderException`, it will throw an exception if what you've annotated with `@RequestHeader` is missing, so you will get an exception like this:

> Missing request header 'Etag' for method parameter of type int

And when the request header is present but not valid this exception will be thrown:

> Invalid request header provided.